# Есть способ проверять включена ли в настройках нужная раскладка клавиатуры?

Tags: java, android

Я сделал приложение. Чтобы с ним полноценно работать необходимо, чтобы в настройках телефона была подключена клавиатура с языком иврит.

Как сделать, чтобы при запуске происходила проверка и если нужная клавиатура не активна, то чтобы предлагалось ее активировать?

Comment: Клавиатура отдельным приложением идет?

Comment: нет... мне кажется во всех телефонах есть перечень доступных клавиатур, просто в настройках она может быть активна либо не активна. Вот это я и хочу проверить

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл вот такой способ проверки доступных клавиатур:

```
 private void printInputLanguages() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        List<InputMethodInfo> ims = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();

        for (InputMethodInfo method : ims) {
            List<InputMethodSubtype> submethods = imm.getEnabledInputMethodSubtypeList(method, true);
            for (InputMethodSubtype submethod : submethods) {
                if (submethod.getMode().equals("keyboard")) {
                    String currentLocale = submethod.getLocale();
                    //Вот тут будет нужная локаль, в Вашем случае должно прийти "iw" или "he"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```